# duplicated levels in factors will be forbidden April 2017. What about the levels function?

Tags: r

In the R-devel list, Martin Maechler posted a message about duplicated levels in factors

> "factors with non-unique (duplicated) levels have been deprecated since 2009 -- are *more* deprecated now ..." [June 4, 2016](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2016-June/072808.html)

It states that in R 3.4, scheduled for April 2017, duplicated levels will cause an error, no longer just a warning.

I wonder why does the levels function not cause a similar warning? Here I combine the first three levels as "a" in two ways, one deprecated.

Example

```
> x <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
> xf <- factor(x, levels = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
    labels = c("a", "a", "a", "d"))
Warning message:
In `levels<-`(`*tmp*`, value = if (nl == nL) 
    as.character(labels) else paste0(labels,  :
    duplicated levels in factors are deprecated
> xf <- factor(x)
> levels(xf) <- c("a", "a", "a", "d")
> xf
[1] a a a d
Levels: a d
```

I would like to understand why the latter is treated differently by R than the former.

This is the documented behavior of levels, I'm not exploiting an unstated element. In ?levels, there is an example in which duplicated levels are allowed. I'll paste it in to save you the lookup.

```
## combine some levels
z <- gl(3, 2, 12, labels = c("apple", "salad", "orange"))
z
levels(z) <- c("fruit", "veg", "fruit")
z
```

Answer (score 0):

Factors are used to create categorical variables. The `Levels` attribute of this variable represents the different categories. A variable cannot have duplicate category. It does not make sense. However, a variable can have duplicate data values of the same category.

The data inside a categorical variable is represented as integer vector. Use `unclass` to see the integer vector. The levels attribute represents the categories of this variable. For example the first value of this variable belongs to a particular category and it will be assigned number 1. If it is an ordered factor, then the lowest category will be assigned number 1.

```
x <- c(letters[1:3], letters[1:3])
xf <- factor(x)

xf
# [1] a b c a b c
# Levels: a b c

attributes(xf)
# $levels
# [1] "a" "b" "c" 
# 
# $class
# [1] "factor"

unclass(xf)
# [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
# attr(,"levels")
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
```

If a category does not have values in a variable, then it will be assigned with `NA`.

```
factor(c("a", "b", "c"), levels = c("e", "f", "g"))
# [1] <NA> <NA> <NA>
#   Levels: e f g
```

`labels` is an optional argument used to change the name of the category. If the variable has data values according to the levels argument then the value in the labels argument will be given to it. Notice the value "e" is given the category "h".

```
factor(c("a", "b", "e"), levels = c("e", "f", "g"), labels = c("h", "i", "j"))
# [1] <NA> <NA> h   
# Levels: h i j
```

Now `levels()` is a replacement function used to change the data present inside a factor variable. The data used in the `levels()` function must correspond to the factor variable. Otherwise garbage is created.

```
xf
# [1] a b c a b c
# Levels: a b c
```

The values with "a" is changed to "e", "b" to "f", "c" to "g". This example shows how to properly convert the category names of a factor variable.

```
levels(xf) <- c("e", "f", "g", "e", "f", "g")
> xf
# [1] e f g e f g
# Levels: e f g
```

Now the garbage type: Notice that the data does not correspond to the factor variable `xf`. To see the integer vector, use `unclass(xf)`.

```
levels(xf) <- c("m", "m", "m", "n", "n", "n")
xf
# [1] m m m m m m
# Levels: m n
```

Comment: This doesn't help me understand why R factor() and levels()<- set attributes differently  when there are duplicate labels.  We agree they are different.  I'm reading R source code now to try to see the reason for the difference.  factor() uses levels() in the 4th to last line. Why doesn't the use of unique() inside levels fix the original problem?  I'll keep studying :)

Comment: why would you have duplicate categories in a factor variable?

Comment: @pauljohn32 In your code `xf <- factor(x, levels = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
    labels = c("a", "a", "a", "d"))` , you are trying to create a factor with duplicate categories, which is invalid operation on a factor variable. For example, the values in labels will override levels arguments.

Comment: `factor()` is used a create a new categorical variable. `levels()` is used to modify the categorical variable. Both have different purpose - create | modify

Comment: If you use `unique` as in `xf <- factor(x, levels = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), labels = unique(c("a", "a", "a", "d")))`, then you will get error for conflicting lengths between levels and labels argument

Comment: However, this will succeed because the length of levels and unique(labels) are identical. In addition, the naming of the categories changed. `xf <- factor(x, levels = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), labels = unique(c("a", "a", "a", "d", "b", "c")))`

Comment: labels argument is used with exclude argument. `xf <- factor(x, levels = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), labels = unique(c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c")), exclude = "d")` . Here the category "d" is removed from the factor variable `xf`

Comment: using unique(levels) and unique(labels) will succeed `xf <- factor(x, levels = unique(c("a", "b", "c", "d")), labels = unique(c("a", "a", "a", "d", "b", "c")))`

Comment: The key here is `length(levels) = length(labels)`. If you see the usage of the function `factor`, it indicates `levels = labels`, alluding to the values in the labels argument will be assigned to levels argument. Check this code `xf <- factor(x, labels = unique(c("a", "a", "a", "d", "b", "c")))`

Comment: categorical variable: `factor()` - create; `levels()` - modify.

Comment: categorical variable `factor()` arguments: 1. `levels` - indicate the different categories;  2. `labels` - change the name of the categories as specified in `levels` argument;  3. `exclude` - remove a category from the variable.

Comment: When using `levels(xf) <-  new_data` function, `unique(new_data)` should not be used unless, the data in factor variable conforms to the data in `unique(new_data)`.

Comment: This question `Why doesn't the use of unique() inside levels fix the original problem?` is valid, but that is not how the `levels` argument in `factor()` is implemented as we see in the above examples. The data analyst needs to control the uniqueness of the categories specified in a factor variable

Comment: Thanks, this is helping me understand better the question I need to ask from the R developers.  Type "factor". 4 lines from bottom it calls levels(). That call to `levels()<-` inside factor() triggers the deprecation warning. A different method gets called after the factor object exists. Without allowing duplicate levels in factor(), still possible to allow duplicate labels in same way that `levels<-.factor` allows. The difference traces back to some C code I don't understand yet.